# Travis ci not triggered from github

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, build, travis-ci

Suddenly, Travis has stopped works with my github repository.

after many trys to fix it, i even deleted to original repository and created another one,

but travis just do not recognize the repo.

next to the repo on travis : "
There are no builds for this repo yet"

even when i click on trigger build, nothing happens.

There is .travis.yml in the repo

.travis.yml

[my Travis File.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYgX1.png)

Comment: You should replace Travis CI with GitHub Actions or any other continuous integration app. Travis is kinda old, and sometimes the runs do not trigger. I recommend using GitHub Actions instead.

Comment: Do you use travis-ci.org or do you migrated already to travis-ci.com? The .org is about to be ceased " Since June 15th, 2021, the building on travis-ci.org is ceased. Please use travis-ci.com from now on." Maybe you can give it try with .com.